# Java Module module-info.java duplicate

Tags: java, eclipse, module, java-platform-module-system

I have created a project, Inside the Project, there One source folder, have taken name as feeding, created packages, classes, module-info.java file into it. After Then, Another source folder created,  have taken name as care, created packages, classes, But while creating module-info.java into care folder facing issue duplicate module-info.java
I am sharing a screenshot of the project, Here, If I am trying to add module-info.java file then the project getting elapsed means project even not opening, [image]trying to open in type hierarchy then showing Duplicate module-info.java. Please have a concern.

Comment: It looks like you are following an example with multiple modules in one project. Modularization is all about encapsulation (for example, each module has its own dependencies). Putting multiple modules in one project would break the encapsulation. This structure does not make sense and is therefore not allowed in Eclipse, which means you can not have more than one `module-info.java` file in a project.

Comment: Thank you very much Howlger.